# Error while running HBase Java Client

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a remote Java Client using HBase Java API connectin to HBase. My Java client is running on Wondows, and trying to connect to my DEV Hadoop cluster.
I added the hbase-site.xml from the hbase/conf of the DEV Hadoop cluster. I am getting the below excpetion:

```
ERROR zookeeper.ZKConfig: no valid quorum servers found in zoo.cfg
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: An error is 
preventing HBase from connecting to ZooKeeper**
```

Below is my zoo.cfg file from the DEV server:

```
dataDir=/var/ibm/biginsights/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
tickTime=2000
maxClientCnxns=300
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
syncLimit=2
initLimit=5
server.1=qabcdbddn03.local:2888:3888
server.2=qabcdbddn02.local:2888:3888
server.3=qabcdbddn01.local:2888:**
```

Below is the hbase-site.xml that i used:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://HNA-BI-QA/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>qabcdbddn03.local,qabcdbddn02.local,qabcdbddn01.local</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2181</value>
 </property>
```

Java Client:

```
public class HbaseConnection
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {

  HTableDescriptor ht = new HTableDescriptor("User"); 

  ht.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Id"));

  ht.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Name"));

  HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin( config );

  hba.createTable( ht );

 }
}
```

zoo.cfg:

```
dataDir=/var/ibm/biginsights/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
tickTime=2000
maxClientCnxns=300
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
syncLimit=2
initLimit=5
server.1=qabcdbddn03.local:2888:3888
server.2=qabcdbddn02.local:2888:3888
server.3=qabcdbddn01.local:2888:3888
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your java client code as well

Comment: is your zookeeper running??

Comment: @mbaxi - Added my Java client Code

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar - Zookeeper is running

Comment: I am facing similar issues. How did you solve this?